# Verify OAuth2 login information without calling authorization server on every request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, cryptography, digital-signature

## Actors

- **Front-end** (fat client-side Javascript application) which has Facebook access token.
- **Back-end** which 100% relies on OAuth2 authentication. All requests need to be authenticated via Facebook.

To mutate user data on the back-end, I require user to be logged in via Facebook. Ideally, with every request, I would know the Facebook's user ID (the one that `graph.facebook.com/me` provides).

### Question 1

Is there a way to get whatever `graph.facebook.com/me` returns to be signed, so I don't have to call Facebook to verify it with every request, nor store state in my backend?

## Situation 2

If the answer to Question 1 is "no", it means I have to invent my own. I am thinking of the following:

1. The user sends the access token to the backend.
2. Backend calls [token debug API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/debug_token), signs the result with *my* key, and sends back to the client.
3. Every time client does a request, it includes the previously-included blob.
4. Upon every incoming request to the backend, it verifies the signature, which, if matches, means that the request wasn't tampered with and I can trust it is coming from the previously-verified token.

### Question 2

If I employ this scheme (sign the answer from Facebook and send it upon every request), how can I safely implement this? Are there resources I could read up which would tell me:

1. Things to be cautious about with this scheme.
2. Which signature algorithm to use, how to safely verify the signatures.
3. How to avoid common types of attacks and stupid mistakes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what exactly you want to do, but I think you should have a look at the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests

Quote:

> Graph API calls can be made from clients or from your server on behalf of clients. Calls from a server can be better secured by adding a parameter called appsecret_proof.
>
> Access tokens are portable. It's possible to take an access token generated on a client by Facebook's SDK, send it to a server and then make calls from that server on behalf of the person. An access token can also be stolen by malicious software on a person's computer or a man in the middle attack. Then that access token can be used from an entirely different system that's not the client and not your server, generating spam or stealing data.
>
> You can prevent this by adding the appsecret_proof parameter to every API call from a server and enabling the setting to require proof on all calls. This prevents bad guys from making API calls with your access tokens from their servers. If you're using the official PHP SDK, the appsecret_proof parameter is automatically added.

Comment: Almost there, but I want the reverse: I want the response from Facebook to be signed, so I can send that value to the user and trust it when the user sends it back.

Comment: Not possible. Not implemented